# Url aliases for Drupal 7 Views page

Tags: views, path-aliases

I have a view which has the path set to events/%, where the wildcard will the the nid of, for example, a department. The view will display all events for a particular department.

I want to be able to change the second nid argument to be an alias, such as events/programming. I don't see this option in the standard Pathauto settings. I found a module which almost does this (only for taxonomy terms), https://drupal.org/project/view_alias, but its only for D6.

Is ther anything for d7, and if not, what would be the best hook to implement to make this change?

EDIT:
There was a suggestion to use the Extended Path Aliases module, but I was not able to get that to work properly, and requires you to hack core (or install hte PECL library). I found a different module, subpathauto, which seems to do the same thing with out core hacking and it also says that it works with views. It still didn't work, this is what happened:

```
Node path: node/24
Node alias: department/[nid]
View path: department/[nid]/conditions

Example alias: department/physical-therapy-department
```

When I use the url of department/24/conditions, I reach the view page I want and the filtered content is displayed. When I use the url department/physical-therapy-department, I reach the correct node page. When I use department/physical-therapy-department/conditions, I DO reach the view page, but it has no content. Clearly the system did not translate physical-therapy-department back to 24 for processing, and the view didn't work.

Does anyone know how to use this module properly?

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [Extended Path Aliases](https://drupal.org/project/path_alias_xt) module..

Project page says

> Would you like your human-readable, SEO-friendly aliases to be carried
>   through on all your tabs, links, **Views**, and blocks, on all your
>   pages, not just on that single aliased base path? If so, then this
>   little module is for you.

Comment: Have you used this module before? I am having a hard time figuring out how to use it. For the moment, I followed the instructions to hack the path.inc file, but where do I set the alias?

Comment: I tried to use the subpathauto module instead, and I still was not successful. I edited my post above.